# Laravel running on Docker is not sending any set-cookie in HTTP response

Tags: php, laravel, docker, cookies

Laravel does not send a Set-cookie response so the Laravel session cookie is not stored in the browser. The session is set to the file adapter and the files are created successfully with the correct permissions.

I have set the Laravel session configuration to the default one shipped with Laravel.

I'm using Laravel Framework 5.5.48.

Can anyone provide any assistance?

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: app.dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www
    environment:
      - "DB_PORT=3306"
      - "DB_HOST=database"
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    networks:
      - t-network
  web:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: web.dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    networks:
      - t-network

  database:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - "MYSQL_DATABASE=t"
      - "MYSQL_USER=homestead"
      - "MYSQL_PASSWORD=secret"
      - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret"
    ports:
      - "33060:3306"
    networks:
      - t-network

volumes:
  dbdata:

networks:
  t-network:
```

vhost.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/public;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        gzip_static on;
    }
}
```

app.dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm

# Copy composer.lock and composer.json
COPY ./src/composer.json /var/www/

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    locales \
    zip \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    vim \
    unzip \
    git \
    curl \
    xvfb \
    libfontconfig \
    wkhtmltopdf

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring zip exif pcntl
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ --with-png-dir=/usr/include/
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd

# Install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Add user for laravel application
RUN groupadd -g 1000 www
RUN useradd -u 1000 -ms /bin/bash -g www www

# Copy existing application directory contents
COPY ./src /var/www

# Copy existing application directory permissions
COPY --chown=www:www . /var/www
RUN chown -R www:www /tmp
RUN chmod -R 777 /tmp

# Change current user to www
USER www

# Expose port 9000 and start php-fpm server
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

web.dockerfile

```
FROM nginx:1.17

ADD vhost.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Comment: Could you provide your nginx or apache configuration?

Comment: And your docker configuration? We can't provide any solution without that.

Comment: @nmfzone I've added the configuration - thanks!

Comment: Does this issue has a fix?

Answer (score 4):

I have the same question.
And when I exec -it into my app container, and run "php artisan serve", and curl -v my login URL, I can't get the response with right set-cookie header set.
So I know that's nothing about Nginx.

I found some places to watch how headers were set.

```
1.vi vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php
addCookieToResponse

2.vi vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php
addCookieToResponse

3.vi vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Response.php
prepare
sendHeaders
```

I found the headers_sent call in sendHeaders was **true** and it directly returns.
So I put parameters in **headers_sent**, and found the bug was I got an empty line as line 1 in one of my route files, that was ridiculous while the same source code runs on other VMs very healthy needing no concern with no bugs! And just in docker, it doesn't work.

After I remove the empty line. I can get my **APP_session** & **SESSION-TOKEN** set back !!!
I'm not very sure if there is some "strict" mode like javascript, for I'm not export of PHP.I'm sure the real reason is not the empty line at top of route file.

Comment: And there is still an issue for me. The Http Post of /login gets a 200 response. And normal VM deployed app will return a 302 response. Still, modify headers_sent, and found there is a var_dump in my code, this makes a faster-response with code 200 before my real 302 response.

Comment: Ok so for me there as a space before <?php in one file in project. thanks your answer was helpful.